# Select the matched row plus next 3 rows followed

Tags: sql, mysql

Table `students` has 3 columns `id`, `name`, and `class`.

I want to select the matched row based on the condition for example if the student's name is `Jhon`, plus the next 3 rows (without any condition) followed by the match row in just one query.

After research, my code below returns only 1 row, or maybe this is not the way of doing what I want:

```
SELECT * FROM `students` AS `parent`

INNER JOIN `students` AS `child`

WHERE `parent`.`name` = ? AND `child`.`id` > `parent`.`id`
 
ORDER BY `child`.`id` ASC LIMIT 3
```

**Note:** I am using PHP Prepared Statements.

Comment: Do you have more than 1 matching row in the database?

Comment: No, all the names are unique.

Comment: [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question). Some sample data will always make a SQL question a lot easier to understand.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might need to change your join criteria from `>` to `>=` and select from the child table instead:

```
SELECT `child`.*
FROM `students` AS `parent`
INNER JOIN `students` AS `child` ON `child`.`id` >= `parent`.`id`
WHERE `parent`.`name` = ?
ORDER BY `child`.`id` ASC
LIMIT 4
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Don't you think `>=` will return the matched row twice?

Comment: It shouldn't - the first row would be identical in both parent and child tables, the following rows would be different.  Just a point of clarity though - did you want three rows total, or the parent plus three extra (ie 4 rows total)?

Comment: I want parent + 3, so 4 yes.

Comment: OK, answer updated accordingly

Answer (score 0):

Use a subquery that returns the `id` that you want in the `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT * 
FROM students 
WHERE id >= (SELECT id FROM students WHERE name = ?) 
ORDER BY id LIMIT 4;
```